# Stuck with this web scraper

Tags: python-2.7, css-selectors, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a program in Python 2.7 with BeautifulSoup that would extract all the profile URLs from this page and subsequent pages

http://www.reaa.govt.nz/Pages/PublicRegisterSearch.aspx?pageNo=1&name=a*&orgName=&location=&licenceNo=&itemsPerPage=100&sortExpression=2

I have been fighting with this program for a long time now and it still dosn't work. I think I am messing up at the CSS selector, but I am not sure what else to try.

Please advise...I am new to programming and python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def re_crawler(pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= pages:
        url = 'http://www.reaa.govt.nz/Pages/PublicRegisterSearch.aspx?pageNo=' + str(page) + '&name=a*&orgName=&location=&licenceNo=&itemsPerPage=100&sortExpression=2'
        code = requests.get(url)
        text = code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
        for link in soup.select('tr.alternate td a[id*=ct100_]'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print (href)
        page += 1

re_crawler(2)
```

Comment: I see in the html that id begins with ctl00_ but in your code it is ct100_, maybe a typo error?

Comment: Thank you so much for noticing that, Birei. I didn't notice it was ctl00_ and it didn't work with that either. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead?

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def re_crawler(pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= pages:
        url = 'http://www.reaa.govt.nz/Pages/PublicRegisterSearch.aspx?pageNo=' + str(page) + '&name=a*&orgName=&location=&licenceNo=&itemsPerPage=100&sortExpression=2'
        code = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
        for link in soup.select('tr.alternate td a[id*=ctl00_]'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print (href)
        page += 1

re_crawler(2)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thank you so much Reuben. Could you please explain why it didn't work with requests, but it did with urlopen? As a learner, I am curious to know :) Thanks once again, very much!

Comment: Actually birei got it right. All I did was to simplify your code a little. If you fix the ctl00 bit, requests would work too.

Comment: I tried that Reuben. Didn't work with my code (requests). Did it work at your end?

Comment: Yes, it did. Just a tad slower.

Comment: Weird, it just doesn't work for me at all. This is exactly what I have on my PyCharm right now and it doesn't work - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15e81a636dd04816c054

Can you see why it isn't working for me? Thanks

Comment: that's what I have too. you could try printing something before and after the `requests.get()` line and see whether thats the issue

Comment: I did that Reuben and it printed both the before and after strings, but still wouldn't run the program. Revised code - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/650962b11928afc07ce7

Comment: try the same with the other potentially blocking parts of the script till the printing fails.

Comment: Did that. It fails to print after `for link in soup.select('tr.alternate td a[id*=ctl00_]'): ` - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3b19cd452586b67339d Please advise

Comment: @pb_ng: Here your gist prints many urls too, so my guess is that you will have to debug by yourself, making a simpler selection first, or looking elsewhere, like your SO environment, if you are redirecting the output, it's part of a bigger project, you are running it from a shell script or similar potential issues.